# Alignment taking into consideration Material design padding

Tags: flutter

I want to show a progress bar with a button on the right side as in the image below. The margin on the left and right should be visually equal. Instead, the spacing on the right is larger than on the left. This is because the `IconButton` I'm using adheres to material design and has a bunch of extra space around it.

[image: Progress Bar]

My code places the progress bar in a `Row`. Above it I also have a label in a `Row`. I want the right-aligned label to be aligned to the button. What's the correct way to align taking into consideration any padding that material design might have added?

Here's what my code looks like:

```
return Container(
        padding: 10,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(children: [Text("Left aligned text"), const Spacer(), Text("Right aligned text")]),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.darkBlue, color: Colors.blue, value: 55, minHeight: 20)),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.stop_circle_outlined),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              )
            ])
          ],
        ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this. I wound up just making my own version of `IconButton` without the padding.